# MC whose transition probabilities have a PDF w.r.t. $\mu$ are reversible w.r.t to $\mu$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Markov Chain with transition probability
$$p(x, dy) \sim N(x, \epsilon)$$
Show that $Y$ is reversible w.r.t to the lebesgue measure . What I have done is just simply used Fubinis theorem to write

$$\int_A p(x, B) dx = \int_A \int_B \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi\epsilon)}} \exp(\frac{-(y-x)^2}{2\epsilon})dy dx = \int_B \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi\epsilon)}} \exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2\epsilon})dx dy = \int_B p(y, A) dy $$

Now the only two things I used are fubini and that the transition probability has a PDF w.r.t. the lebesgue measure.

Did I oversee something or is every Markov Chain which has a PDF w.r.t to a measure $\mu$ also reversible w.r.t to that? Are there generalizations of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reversible example has the *very special feature* that the kernel $p(x,dy)$ has a density $\phi(x,y)$ that is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, i.e., $\phi(x,y)=\phi(y,x)$. This is generally not true and the process would not always be reversible.

Comment: Being a bit more explicit, it is reversible with respect to the Lebesgue measure because the Lebesgue measure has the density $m(x) \equiv 1$, and $m(x) \phi(x,y)=m(y) \phi(y,x)$. (This says nothing new in this context, but draws parallels to cases where you have some other invariant measure).

Comment: @Ian You are quite right! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Still in other words, the Markov chain is such that $Y_{n+1}=Y_n+Z_{n+1}$ for every $n$, where $(Z_n)$ is i.i.d. and independent of $Y_0$ and has a symmetric distribution (and, if I read correctly the faulty notation in the question, here, every $Z_n$ is gaussian $N(0,\epsilon)$, but this is irrelevant). **Every** such chain is reversible with respect to the Lebesgue measure since reversing time morally yields the dynamics $Y\to Y+\hat Z$ with $\hat Z=-Z=Z$ in distribution. ...

Comment: ... In @Byron's notations, $\phi(x,y)=g(y-x)$ where $g$ denotes the density of $Z_n$ and the fact that $g$ is even ($g(z)=g(-z)$ for every $z$) saves the day.